# Why are almost all of the United Nations headquarters located in Europe or America?

Tags: russian-federation, united-nations, soviet-union

Why are almost all of the United Nations headquarters located in Europe or America?

Why aren't there any headquarter of UN department in Asia or Latin America or Africa?

[See this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations#Specialized_agencies):

[image]

Comment: Also worth noting that most nations don't have a UN office.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, I am talking about Russia, a permanent member of UNSC.

Comment: China also doesn't have any big UN offices. Being a member of the security council is not correlated to have a UN office in your borders.

Comment: "Being a member of the security council is not correlated to have a UN office in your borders." --- So what is correlated? Being a Switzerland?

Comment: Being a Switzerland is a good start.

Comment: There IS UN headquarters in Africa, in Nairobi.

Comment: Most UN offices are in places where the bureaucrats can luxuriate in posh circumstances and take advantage of their salaries. They would not put themselves in any position where they might actually have to work or suffer discomfort.

Comment: @sabbahillel on the contrary, the headquarters are in cities with high cost of living.  UN officers who are posted to field offices typically live in far more luxurious circumstances, because they can afford to hire domestic help that is prohibitively expensive in headquarters locations.

Comment: You should reformulate your question in light of the The United Nations Human Settlements Programme being headquartered in Nairobi, Africa.

Comment: @phoog They are paid enough to live in luxurious conditions in the cities that they are posted to.

Comment: @sabbahillel even if that is true, it doesn't explain why the HQ offices tend to be in cities with high costs of living, and rather suggests that they should have been located elsewhere, where bureaucrats could live luxuriously for less money. But it's not entirely true: I know UN bureaucrats who endure 2-hour commutes from Pennsylvania and southern New Jersey. This is not the normal behavior of people drawing luxuriously high salaries.

Comment: @phoog The decision is not up to them. It is the big shots that make those decisions and they deliberately choose the luxury cities. They do not care about the lower levels.

Comment: @sabbahillel and if the big shots were primarily interested in luxury lifestyle they would have chosen cities with lower costs of living. Therefore, luxury was not a primary factor in the decision of where to put the headquarters offices. Anyway, the reasons for those decisions, which were largely made in the middle of the 20th century, largely have to do with post-WWII international politics.  These decisions were not made by the UN's current upper-level officials, either; agencies are in fact now moving large numbers of staff to less expensive locations such as eastern Europe and SE Asia.

Comment: @anonymous: what's the source of this list? Where are UNICEF, UNHCR, UNFPA, etc?

Comment: @phoog, Wikipedia. The link is already provided in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: @anonymous thanks. That list apparently omits the 13 "UN system agencies." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_System.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Where are they?

Six are in Switzerland, presumably due to its reputation for neutrality.  Four of them seem to have replaced organizations that predated the United Nations.

Three are in Italy, all related to food and agriculture.  Two are newer, so they might have split off from the first.

Two are in Austria.  Note that at the time that they were established, Austria was a neutral country that bordered the eastern bloc countries dominated by the Soviet Union.  The first came shortly after the Soviets and the western allies withdrew from their postwar occupation in 1955.

Two are in the United States of America, both related to money and banking.  The US was the largest economy and expected to fund the rebuilding of Europe and Japan.  Giving it control of the banking organizations probably made sense at that point.

One in the United Kingdom, related to maritime operations.  The UK has a long history as a noted naval power with lots of economic activity related to shipping.

One in France, related to culture, science, and education.

One in Canada, related to aviation.

One in Spain, related to tourism.

Only four located in permanent Security Council members.

#### Why?

Note that most of them were established shortly after World War II, so they were likely intended to draw the European countries closer together.  Putting them in Europe made sense at that time, particularly as Switzerland had held the immediate predecessor to the UN:  the League of Nations.

Looking at the [League of Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations), most of Africa was considered colonies of other powers.  Most of Asia was the Soviet Union and China.

In general, Europe and North America provide most of the funding for the United Nations.  It would be unsurprising if they wanted to keep track of their investments.  Similarly, note that most US agencies are located close to Washington, DC even though their clients are elsewhere.  For example, the Interior department oversees national parks, mostly land in the west.  DC is in the urbanized east, while a great deal of rural land is more centrally located.

Inertia keeps organizations where they were founded, even as circumstances change later.  Washington, DC is reasonably located in the middle of the original thirteen colonies, but the [center of the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_center_of_U.S._population) is now in Missouri (closer to St. Louis or Kansas City).  Yet they've never moved the capital.

Comment: Nice analysis. I just noticed, thanks to only two being listed in the US, that several agencies with HQ in New York are omitted.  But the basic answer remains: it reflects the Euro-American dominance of international affairs after the second world war. I'm pretty sure Austria was not in the Soviet sphere, though, certainly not in 1957 or 1967.

Comment: The fact that many member nations of the U.N. today were colonies at its inception is the key historical fact. Not only was much of the world in colonial status when the U.N. was founded, one of the most effective U.N. programs (in terms of achieving its stated goals anyway) was the effort to grant independence to colonies.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [old website,](http://www.unrussia.ru/en) but with updated information, about the United Nations in Russia. [One section](http://www.unrussia.ru/en/agencies/un-information-centre-moscow-unic) specifies about the UN Information Centre in Moscow (UNIC).

> Established in 1948, the UN Information Centre in Moscow is the oldest
>   UN office in the country. It is in a way a compact UN "information
>   agency". It is also a repository of knowledge, global best practices
>   and standards in a wide range of areas – from environmental protection
>   to outer space – being at the same time a sort of a local UN public
>   relations service.

And contact information:

```
UN Information Centre in Moscow
Moscow
Leontyevsky pereulok, 9, 125009
Tel: (495) 787-21-07
Fax: (495) 787-21-43
E-mail: unic.moscow@unic.org
Website: http://www.unic.ru
```

[EDIT] (after question edit and comments)

I think that HQs are located only within some countries because of the following:

- relations with **Soviet Union** and then Russian Federation were far from being good. UN existence intersected a lot with the Cold War just for a start.
- relations with **China** were far from "unicorns and rainbows", because of the communist regime which had problems for decades regarding [human rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_rights_in_China))
- **other countries**: most probably because a headquarters require special security and infrastructure that is not available in less developed countries

Comment: I am talking about headquarters. Like Switzerland has headquarters of several UN departments. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_specialized_agencies_of_the_United_Nations

Comment: > then after the invasion of Taiwan: what exactly are you talking about? Who invaded whom in Taiwan?

Comment: @dannyf - thanks, I have removed wrong information.

Answer (score -2):

> Why are all United nations headquarters in Europe or America?

The UN is primarily a west-led and west-funded organization. So it makes sense that its employees are primarily citizens from the western countries, and such.

That's pretty much true for most of the world institutions.

Comment: Somebody argued that Russia is a part of the west. So,what about Russia?

Comment: > Somebody argued that Russia is a part of the west. people argue all sorts of crazy things. that doesn't mean you have to agree to any of them.

Comment: Most employees in headquarters locations are foreigners, so that doesn't seem to be the reason.